# What is the difference between {active: "yes"} and {"active": "yes"}?

Tags: javascript, json

I've used FireBug to test the two cases and they seem pretty similar by result:

```
>>> var x = {"active": "yes"}
>>> x.active
"yes"
>>> var x = {active: "yes"}
>>> x.active
"yes"
```

But I'm pretty sure there is some difference between these two, maybe even performance related difference. Bottom line - I'd like to know if there is a difference between {active: "yes"} and {"active": "yes"}.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Both are valid. However there are certain keywords you cant use like `delete` so in order to avoid that you wrap them in quotes so they are not treated literally by the ECMAScript parser and instead are explicitly specified as strings.

Additionally, the [JSON spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627) requires that keys have quotes around them:

> A string begins and ends with
> quotation marks

So `{key:'value'}` is not valid JSON but is valid JS, while `{"key":"value"}` is valid JS and JSON.

Examples of keywords and invalid/ambiguous keys:

```
>>> ({delete:1})
SyntaxError: Unexpected token delete
>>> ({'delete':1})
Object
```

Another example:

```
>>> ({first-name:'john'})
SyntaxError: Unexpected token -
>>> ({'first-name':'john'})
Object
>>> ({'first-name':'john'})['first-name']
"john"
```

Comment: Also many JSON parses won't handle unquoted attributes. In Chrome for example: `JSON.parse('{"a":3}')`  is ok, `JSON.parse('{a:3}')` raises an exception.

Comment: Actually `{"key":'value'}` isn't valid JSON due to the requirement of double quotes around keys and _string_ values.

Comment: @Marcel J.: Many JSON parsers won't handle that because `{a:3}` is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 11):

Both are valid JavaScript (although some names can only be used quoted, `active` isn't among them).

The latter is invalid JSON (quoted names are mandatory in JSON).

Comment: +1, the important distinction is that one is JSON, and the other isn't.

Comment: @molf: neither are JSON technically ;)

Comment: @Roatin: Sorry? What's not JSON about `{"active": "yes"}`?

Answer (score 3):

Every valid JSON is also valid JavaScript but not every valid JavaScript is also valid JSON as JSON is a proper subset of JavaScript:

> JSON ⊂ JavaScript

JSON requires the names of name/value pairs to be quoted while JavaScript doesn’t (as long as they are not reserved keywords).

So your first example `{"active": "yes"}` is both valid JSON and valid JavaScript while the second example `{active: "yes"}` is only valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, `{"active": "yes"}`, `{'active': "yes"}`, `{"active": 'yes'}` and `{active: 'yes'}` are all the same -- if you are using a reserved keyword (as meder points out), you *must* quote the key -- otherwise, the key does not need to be quoted.

In JSON, on the other hand all keys *and* values **must** be quoted with `"`.
`{"active": "yes"}` is valid JSON.
`{'active': "yes"}`, `{"active": 'yes'}` and `{active: 'yes'}` are not.

Comment: JSON only recognizes `"` for quoting strings, so only the first example is valid JSON.

Comment: `{"active": 'yes'}` still isn't valid. The quoting rules are for all strings, not just key names. JSON has a distinct lack of TMTOWTDI :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this for JSON, the name (`active`) must be enclosed in quotes. It will still work in JavaScript without it, but it's technically malformed JSON.
See: http://json.org/
Note that the `object`, requires a `string` for the name (the bit before the colon).